# Modifying XML((local file system)) file in browser and saving at same place

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to modify an XML file from browser which is at local file system and save back at same place where it has been picked from browser.

I have searched a lot in google but didn't find any solution. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can read a file from the the local file system, but browsers (and JavaScript) will not ever allow you to save back to the file system.

You have a couple of options:

1 - use cloud storage and avoid the file system all together

2 - Create your own desktop app and wrap a web browser control. Then open/save the file in your own code, and pass it to the browser control.

Comment: Thanks. Actually It is spring web application and each user will have their own XML file. so how cloud storage can be use here?

Comment: You could let them store their XML file on your server, or in Google Drive, or in Skydrive, or whatever makes sense for you.